# "#NUM!" error in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google, google-apps-script-triggers

When trying to Run the following script the result is always a `#NUM! error - (Result is not a number)` in cell `"O5"`

Both the cells are in currency format and I've tried changing them to number as well but still the same error pops up.

```
function substract(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dash = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var a = dash.getRange("O5").getValue;
  
  var cash = ss.getSheetByName('Open Trades');
  var b = cash.getRange("M4").getValue;

 dash.getRange("O5").setValue(a-b);

 }
```

Underlying context :
-I want to create a script function that I will use with daily triggers:

-function will subtract "Daily Fees" (a cell value that changes daily from "Open Trades" sheet) / from "Cash" (a cell in another sheet "Dashboard") and will set the value of the remaining Cash in the same cell (Cash from Dashboard)

**Formula -> 'Dashboard'!O5 = 'Dashboard'!O5 - 'Open Trades'!M4**

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `Range.getValue()` calls are missing their parentheses `()`.

Comment: Thanks! did not notice that! Script works now.